# C# int.TryParse Maybe?

Tags: c#, if-statement

So this is an error I've been trying to figure out but can not seem to fix. .
This is in one function.

```
File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD [VersionText.Tag], true);

private void Version_2_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Version_2_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "Version 2.0";
    VersionText.Tag = 2;
}
```

But `VersionText.Tag` in the first part always gives me this error.

[image]

I heard something with `int.TryParse`, but I can not figure out how to implement it into my code.

I hope I explained it enough.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `string Version_2_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "Version 2.0";`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov That gives one value to both strings

Comment: @LeeTaylor Woah ! Honestly, I didn't even know that's valid syntax. Awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My assumption of the problem is on the line

```
File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD [VersionText.Tag], true);
```

specifically `mcAD [VersionText.Tag]`.

`.Tag` returns type `object`, but the array indexer expects `int`.

If you cast it, it should hopefully get rid of the compile error at least.

```
File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD [(int)VersionText.Tag], true);
```

If `VersionText.Tag` doesn't contain an integer, you'll get a runtime error, however.

Comment: +1: With all the other poor answers, this is the only correct one.

Comment: agreed with @leppie )

Comment: That did it! I'll test now! :D
@Matthew http://prntscr.com/1iirtr this is what happened

Comment: In order to avoid possible runtime error you can use int.TryParse method. Something like this: int result = -1; Int32.TryParse(VersionText.Tag, out result); if (result != -1) {//your code}

Comment: @MatthewH in that case, it's best to show us the format of VersionText in your question. I.e. how the variables are declared.

Comment: @PavelPatino you missed the second parameter **too**. You forgot `out`.

Comment: @user1429899 and @pavel since `int.TryParse` expects type string as its first parameter, it wont compile.  You could use `Convert.ToInt32` however.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson What you mean?

Comment: Show us the code for that class so we can see the types of the variables. That's what confuses us. We didn't know the types so we had to guess. If you look at my question regarding a C++ 128 bit integer, you'll see that I posted the definition of the structure with only the relevant functions. That's a good question. This was an OK one. If we knew what types they were, it would be a good one :)

Comment: Just wrap `VersionText.Tag` with `int.TryParse(VersionText.Tag, out result)`  (I've never used tags, I'm guessing they're strings.)  To make it more readable you could make a method like `VersionNumber()` that contains the `int.TryParse(VersionText.Tag, out result)`, and have it return result.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Okay, bear with me hear cause I'm trying to get used to all the lingo. I'm still new to this. When you say types of variables, are you asking how I'm writing everything out? The code that looked like...
`private void Version_2_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Version_2_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "Version 2.0";
    VersionText.Tag = 2;
}`

Is how I'm writing out the variables if I can guess what you're talking about. That code happens when the user selects a version from a context menu.
But each version copy the file to a different location. 
Hold on...

Comment: The locations are determined with the `string[] mcAD = {"location", "location", "location"}`
Then the tag, either 1, 2, or 3, would determine the location. 
Right now I have the code set up like `File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD [(int)VersionText.Tag], true);`
But it kept giving me this error which you already have seen
http://prntscr.com/1iirtr

I hope this explains everything. I'm really trying to understand. Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: @MatthewH by types, I mean if your class is `class X { int v; string z; }`, tell us `v` is an `int`, and `z` is a `string`.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson I do not think I have those. Maybe.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson I still need some help figuring this out and I can not go to chat yet so.